# Distortion in the whole mesh when applying scaling to a part

Tags: modeling

I am new in blender. I am modelling a cup wherein I want to reduce the radius of the lower part. But when I select the lower circumference using Alt+ click and then press S to scale it down. the whole mesh get deformed as shown in the pictures. Can anybody help me where I am wrong?
[image: lower circumference selected]

[image: upper portion also get deformed]

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible that you have enabled [proportional editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html) with random pattern?

[image]

You can disable it by click on the blue circle and selecting disable or by using the shortcut, o.
[image]